# How to add My Order link in My Account dropdown?

Tags: magento2, layout

I have overriden app/code/Test/Sales/view/frontend/layout/default.xml file

```
  <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Link" name="order-list-link" after="wish-list-link"/>
    </referenceBlock>

 <move element="top.links" destination="customer"/>
```

But no effect.

Comment: Update your Full path here

Comment: @Magento2 added full path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `default.xml` in `app/design/frontend/your-theme-namespace/yourtheme/Magento_Sales/layout` with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link-top" after="my-account-link" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

My Orders link will appear as in the image.

[image]

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. In my case I didn't make a Magento_Sales, rather, I added your code in my `/app/design/frontend/themefolder/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Comment: Do you know how to specify it's location among other links. Like to have it after My Wish List and before Sign Out.

Comment: @MJoraid if you want it after wishlist link then change argument in after attribute to wish-list-link. For more on layout instructions, you can go through https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Comment: Anshu, I truly appreciate your reply. My `My Orders` shows at the bottom of the list after `Sign Out` no matter what value I put in `after="wish-list-link"` or `after="my-account-link"` even `after="-"` or `before="-"`. I even tried to move `Sign Oud` which I assume is `authorization-link` but it always remains the last one. If I move `authorization-link` to another container e.g. `panel.search` it actually gets moved.

Answer (score 0):

***I am posting this here, because my reputation is <50***

@Anshu Mishra

I have tried your code, it works.

My default.xml is placed at:

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Theme/layout
```

There is an issue that i am facing. The "My Orders" comes at the bottom of the dropdown. Even below Sign out. How can I have it placed as shown in the image attached in your answer above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a discussion forum. If you have a new question, please ask a new one rather than posting an answer.